# what is the new approach to developing C# apps with a stand-alone database?

Tags: sql-server, desktop-application

I'm looking into developing single deployment applications, traditional desktop applications with simple database(s) embedded.  By my understanding Microsoft have removed support for MSSQL Compact Edition in the newer versions of Visual Studio.

I've read that the approach recommended by them is to use the Express version of MSSQL, however I'm failing to understand how an application with an Express SQL database embedded in it would be able to run on a machine without the SQL service installed and running.

Am I missing something here?  I've hunted around Google for the last few hours, is the only solution to use a 3rd party technology like SQLite?

Comment: You are correct. It would need to have sql express installed on the client machine. Your installer should be savvy enough to know that sql express isn't installed and be able to install it. That is pretty common so there should be plenty of examples all over the place for this.

Comment: Many thanks for the clarification, there arent any sources online that I could find that specifically state this